# How to create Select inside ng-repeat (angularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with SELECT options, when I do my first choice the content of my SELECT becomes empty.

here are my app.html && app.js

**app.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nodeCss.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="Webapp">

    <h1>Module Opale</h1>
    Titre<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
    Metadonnées<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
    Objectif du module<input type="text" placeholder="Objectif">
    <script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_Opale.html">
        <button class="addchild" ng-click="addChild(data)">addChild</button>
        <button ng-show="data.parent" ng-click="addSibling(data)">addSibling</button>
        <button class="delete" ng-click="delete(data)" ng-show="data.nodes.length > 0">Delete children</button>
        <div>
            <select  ng-model="choices" ng-options="choice as choice.name for choice in choices"></select>{{choices}}
            <div ng-switch on="choices.id">
                <div ng-switch-when="1"><h3>Division</h3>
                    Titre division<input type="text" /><br />
                    Titre court<input type="text" /><br />
                </div>

                <div ng-switch-when="2"><h4>Grain de contenu</h4>
                    Titre<input type="text" /><br />
                    Titre court<input type="text" /><br />
                    <h5>Information</h5>
                    Titre<input type="text" /><br />
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="70"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="data in data.nodes" ng-include="'tree_item_Opale.html'"></li>
        </ul>
    </script>

        <ul ng-controller="treeCtrl">
            <li ng-repeat="data in tree" ng-include="'tree_item_Opale.html'"></li>
        </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rightClickDirective.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module("Webapp", ["ngSanitize","directive.contextMenu"])


    .controller("treeCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.choices=[
        {id:'1',name:'Division'},
        {id:'2',name:'Grain de contenu'},




    $scope.delete = function(data) {
        data.nodes = [];
    };
    $scope.addSibling = function(data) {
        var post = data.parent.nodes.length + 1;
        var newName = data.parent.name + '-' + post;
        data.parent.nodes.push({name: newName,nodes: [], parent: data.parent});
    };
     $scope.addChild = function(data) {
        var post = data.nodes.length + 1;
        var newName = data.name + '-' + post;
        data.nodes.push({name: newName,nodes: [], parent: data});
    };
    $scope.tree = [{name: "Node", nodes: []}];    
}]);
```

**nodeCss.css**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    border-left: 1px dashed #ddd;
}
li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
button {
  background: #63AE12;
  color: #FFF;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  margin: 9px;
}
button.addchild {
  background: #3094E7;
}
button.delete {
  background: orange;
}
```

when I add child or sibling and I want to select an option, the first add the options are available but when i add second time the options disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you use `choices`, which is your array, as your `ng-model`. You need a different variable for `ng-model`. So what happens is that when you select, your choice becomes the only available option since it's your new array (it's binded because of the `ng-model`).

Do something like this:

```
<select  ng-model="modelChoices" ng-options="choice as choice.name for choice in choices"></select>{{modelChoices}}
```